# Is there a way to start/restart/stop apache server on linux as non-root user?

Tags: linux, apache

I'd like to know if it is possible for non-root user on linux (i'm using openSUSE) to run apache without using sudo command. Take into account that the user is in the same group as apache (wwwrun).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IF I knew I would answer, but instead I'll tell you that this is not a programming question :) Seriously, though, I do not know the answer. It's a great question, in fact.

Comment: Thanks and yes,I was not sure if this question fits in programming, however I gave it a try :).

Comment: It's arguably programming-related, as the most common reason for wanting to do this, in my experience, is so that a programmer can more easily restart apache on his development box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems pointed out above by benlumley, i.e. log files and reserved ports, can easily be overcome by configuring the log directory and port in your httpd.conf.

Comment: There is no way around privilegied port access limitations without privileged acces.

Comment: "Configuring the... port in your httpd.conf" is a way around privileged port access limitations, as you can choose a non-privileged port to listen on.

Comment: Oh ok, I had not realized a non standard port would suit perfectDay.

Answer (score 12):

You can run Apache as any user.  Just make sure that it is set up to only use allowed resources (directories, files and most importantly listening on a non privileged port).

To have it appear on HTTP’s standard port 80 (which is priviledged) you will have to setup, **as root** a redirection to your real Apache server.  The easiest way is probably using iptables.  For example if your Apache server is listening on port 8080:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 --syn -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

If you can not configure the server like this (or have your sysadmin do that once for all) you will have to use a non privileged port (something like `Listen 8080`) and access it using an URL that looks like http://www.example.com:8080/

Comment: The problem is I cannot become root, so I'm looking for a way how to overcome everything that needs to be done as root. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you have sudo installed you can create a file: /etc/sudoers.d/apache2reload with the following content:

```
username    ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Wouldn't do that. Can't understand why so many people posted this option. By default, once you do the sudo command you don't have to enter the password to run another sudo command, thus giving them free root access.

Comment: This wasn't "default" on the two systems I just tried (Ubuntu 14.04, SLES 11) - worth checking for yourself.

Comment: This is the right answer. Changing the user apache runs as (which is not usually root anyway) does not make a difference. @dtc's objection is based on a misunderstanding about how the sudoers conf works.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: No

The reason for it is that only root can bind ports below 1024.

Long answer: check out http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/386

Once you overcome the problem with the ports, I don't think there will be any more trouble. Just remember that the user that apache runs under need to have write-access to the log files and maybe some other files as well.

However, if you run it without sudo, the spawner will probably not be able to change the user, so apache will be being run as the user starting it, instead of the apache user.

But what is the reason you don't want to run sudo? It is only the spawner process that is being run as root, the rest of them are being run under the apache user.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to give out sudo access, you can also create a setuid wrapper program.  For example:

httpdctrl.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <strings.h>

// allow start/stop/restart of apache by non-root users

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *cmd, *cmd2, *usage;

  // UPDATE THIS LINE:
  cmd = "/your/path/to/httpd/sbin/apachectl";
  cmd2 = "apachectl";
  usage = "Usage: COMMAND [start|stop|restart]\n";

  if ( argc != 2 ) {
    printf(usage);
    exit(1);
  }

  setegid(0);
  seteuid(0);
  setgid(0);
  setuid(0);

  if ( strncmp(argv[1], "start", 5) == 0 ) {
    if (execl(cmd, cmd2, "start", (char*)0) < 0) {
     perror("Error");
    }
  } else if ( strncmp(argv[1], "stop", 4) == 0 ) {
    if (execl(cmd, cmd2, "stop", (char*)0) < 0) {
     perror("Error");
    }
  } else if ( strncmp(argv[1], "restart", 7) == 0 ) {
    if (execl(cmd, cmd2, "restart", (char*)0) < 0) {
     perror("Error");
    }
  } else {
    printf(usage);
    exit(1);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

Update the path at:

```
  // UPDATE THIS LINE:
  cmd = "/your/path/to/httpd/sbin/apachectl";
```

Then compile and change permisions with

```
gcc -o httpdctrl httpdctrl.c
sudo chown root:root httpdctrl
sudo chmod u+s httpdctrl
```

Now the httpdctrl is owned by root, and setuid will run it as root.

IMPORTANT:  Make sure the start/stop script and all parent dirs are owned by root as well.  Also remove write access to files and dirs for 'other'.  Basically, you don't want someone to be able to edit or change the dirs/files that are executed with root.

Answer (score 1):

The two problems I can think of that you need to overcome are:

1. Permissions on log files - these may well be already set to allow wwwrun to access them, but its often an issue.
2. Non root user accessing a privileged port (80) - not sure if/how you can change this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this by granting execute access to the group owning the Apache control program (e.g., "chmod g+x apachectl"). If this is doesn't work by itself try also setting the owner SUID bit on the program (something along the lines of "chmod u+s apachectl").

The first step allows users in your wwwrun group to execute the apachectl program. The second step makes it so that when the group runs the program, it runs with the program owners privileges.

Let me know if this works, I'm a little rusty with file execution SUID, but I can help look into it further if you still have problems.

Be sure you understand the consequences of setting the SUID bit before you do this though.

Answer (score 0):

You can "setuid" to allow non-root users to run apachectl as root (without having to authenticate as root).

[Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#Demonstration)

Edit: Should mention that you require root access to set this up in the first place :-)

Comment: I thought the  same. Tried it and it doesn't fly.(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: My mistake - setuid is generally ignored for shell scripts (for security reasons).

Check out the answer by Emanuel.

Comment: Emanuel's answer does fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can view your privileges with sudo -l, from here you might find that you have access to the restart command, but maybe not start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

Some link I found gave the most beneficial answer for this. Technically, it's still acting as root but you can chmod u+s the apache2 and apache2ctl (if you're also using the second) loading files. This allows you to run them with root access but still be of a user that holds the same permissions, keeping security intact (unless apache or apache2ctl were to do crazier things which I doubt they are).

Answer (score -1):

you can use supervisor to run the apache