# How to reload Apache2 on remote server via ssh from MacOS without sudo?

Tags: apache2, reload

I am using a shared hosting. I am trying to reload Apache2 on that remote server via ssh from my PC with MacOS.

I tried `service apache2 reload`, but it says `service: command not found`.

I saw `sudo apachectl restart`, but the Hosting Company doesn't allow me to use sudo.

Is there any way to reload Apache2 in such a case without sudo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to start/restart/stop apache server on linux as non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525672/is-there-a-way-to-start-restart-stop-apache-server-on-linux-as-non-root-user)

Comment: I edited the question. 
It does not answer, because the Hosting Company doesn't allow to edit httpd.conf.

Comment: Looks like you are limited by your hosting company, if they "lock" you, you might never be able to reload apache